# нужно сделать что б при клике на ссылку, скролилась страница до определённого места

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка, href

```
При клики на эту ссылку...
<a href="#" class="one" id="one">01</a>

Должно скролится сюда
<article class="article" id="one">


Есть такой код JS, не знаю как правильно в нем расставить классы и id 

$(".learn-more").on("click","a", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
      top = $(id).offset().top;
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы скролилось до определенного места, необходимо обозначить id этого блока. Не класс. Вам необходимо (без js кода) написать в ссылке:

```
href="#one".
```

Для этого не требуется писать код на джаваскрипте. анимацию прокрутки очень просто прописать в css.
И ещё один момент: одно значение идентификатора (id) может быть *только* у одного элемента (а у вас id="one" в двух(!) местах). Если элементы повторяются по свойствам, указывайте классы, их можно прописывать так: class="class1 class2 class3..." и каждому задавать css-свойства.